# gmap3 click marker for directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I have a page with a gmap3 map display and one marker with an address set:

```
$("#map_canvas").gmap3({
        map: {
            options: {
                maxZoom: 15,
                draggable: false,
                scrollwheel: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                //panControlOptions: {
                //    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
                //},
                zoomControl: false,
                //zoomControlOptions: {
                //    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                //    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
                //},
                mapTypeControl: false

            }
        },
        infowindow: {
            address: venueAddress,
            options: {
                content: markerInfo
            }
        },
        marker: {
            address: venueAddress
        }
    }, "autofit");
```

What I'd like, is that when the marker is clicked by the user (or the text that appears in the infoWindow of the marker (this may be more correct)), that the user is sent to a google map page where they can get directions to this address.

I can construct the HTML in the 'content' of the infoWindow's options, so constructing an anchor with an href to something like www.google.com/maps/ may be the way, but I'm not sure if there's a standard URL to use when doing this.

Comment: what do you mean by manage the directions? what directions?

Comment: Edited the post - by 'manage directions' I meant "use google maps to provide directions to the provided marker's location" from whatever source address they choose.

Comment: you need to use googlemaps directions service. You set the `origin` to the the users location or whatever the starting point is and the `destination` to the marker the user has selected - and example of the directions service can be found here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

Comment: There's no way of sending the user to a google map page with the destination already set, and where they can simply decide their own starting point? I like the simple look of a small map with a marker (destination) on it. I can easily add html to the window above the marker, built into gmap3, and if possible I'd rather not clutter my page with directions. Would rather send the user to google maps to do that.

Comment: To be honest I dont know....